# Redirect Form Action to Controller (404 error on form submit)

Tags: module, magento-1, controllers, forms, action

I'm new to Magento. 
Need to create an extension which will enable to add comments to products on 'product view' pages.
I created a new tab next to "descriptions" and "reviews" and added the form, but can't put the correct form action which will load the controller file, save the input information and then save it in the database.
Read lot of different articles,but couldn't figure this out.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

This is the form action line in app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\productcomments\productcomments.phtml

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('productcomments/index/savecomment'); ?>" id="product-view-add-comment">
```

Here is my indexController.php content:

```
class Cpstest_ProductComments_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function savecommentAction()
    {
        echo "Hello";
    }
}
```

And I added the block information (tab "Product Comments") in `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\catalog.xml`
like this:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.comments" as="additional" template="productcomments/productcomments.phtml">
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Product Comments</value></action>
</block>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<module>Cpatest_ProductComments</module>
```

I am making some assumptions, but it seems like this should instead be `Cpstest_ProductComments`. Now that you have added the file paths, it looks like your controller filename is incorrect. It should be: `controllers\IndexController.php` (note the plural controllers).

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. Yes, you are right, it should be Cpstest instead of Cpatest. I made a correction, but it still doesn't work. I'm getting a 404 error after submitting the form.

Comment: @bestwebdevs - cleared the Magento cache?

Comment: Yeah, I did, but the error is still there

Comment: @bestwebdevs - can you add the file/directory structure of your extension to the question?

Comment: Sure, I did. Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: @bestwebdevs - Was hoping to see a listing of all files/directories in your extension (i.e. `app\code\local\...`).

Comment: I added the file locations for extension. I suggested that should add the block information in my own extension layout file instead of catalog.xml, but when I did it the tab stopped showing up.

Comment: @bestwebdevs - have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Now my controller file has been loaded.
But it jumps to http://cpstest1.dev/index.php/productcomments/index/savecomment/
Is there a way to redirect it back to the form submit page?

Comment: @bestwebdevs - good to hear, [you can redirect to another route from there](https://www.apptha.com/blog/magento-url-redirect-from-controller/), but that was not part of your original question. I am not going to write your whole extension for you, just trying to help you get going. :)

Comment: Sure lol  I was not going to ask you write the whole extension. Thanks for your help. No more questions ;)

Comment: @bestwebdevs - You are welcome, good luck. Please mark my answer as accepted, that is how to mark a question as resolved on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't activated your extension, to do so make sure that you already created the file:

> app/etc/modules/Cpstest_ProductComments.xml

With the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Cpstest_ProductComments>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Cpstest_ProductComments>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Clear the cache, and from admin go to System > Advanced > Advanced and see if the extension name is listed.

Comment: thanks for your answer. fantasticrice 's updated reply already resolved the issue.